# Cant get my data from my database into my Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-activity, custom-adapter

I have problems getting my Products out of my SQL Light Database into my Spinner. I also use a CustomAdapter to do this. When i click on the spinner nothing happens.

My classes:

_CustomAdapter

```
class _CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyProduct>{

private Activity context;
ArrayList<MyProduct> product;
public _CustomAdapter(Activity context, int resource, int bezID, ArrayList<MyProduct>
        product) {
    super(context, resource, bezID, product);
    this.context = context;
    this.product = product;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyProduct current = product.get(position);
    TextView label = new TextView(context);
    label.setTextSize(30);
    label.setText(current.getBeschreibung());
    return label;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout._spinneritem, parent, false);
    MyProduct current = product.get(position);
    ImageView profile = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgProd);
    profile.setBackgroundResource(current.getImage());
    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.bezProd);
    name.setText(current.getBeschreibung());
    return row;
}
```

}

ActivityClass

```
public class SortimentActivity extends Activity {

EditText preis;
EditText kommentar;
Button okB;
ProductDao pd;
Spinner spinProducts;
MyProduct selected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sortiment);


    preis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.preis);
    kommentar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.kommentar);
    okB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bOK);

    this.deleteDatabase("vegi.db");
    SQLiteDatabase db = new OpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<MyProduct> products= new ArrayList<MyProduct>();
    pd = new ProductDao(db);

    try{
        products=(ArrayList<MyProduct>)pd.getAll();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }

    spinProducts= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.products);
    _CustomAdapter adapter = new _CustomAdapter(this,R.layout._spinneritem, R.id.bezProd, products);
    spinProducts.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinProducts.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            selected =(MyProduct) spinProducts.getSelectedItem();
            String a = String.valueOf(selected.getPreis());

            preis.setText(a);
            kommentar.setText(selected.getBeschreibung());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preis.setText("");
            kommentar.setText("");
        }
    });



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sortiment, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void okClick(View v){
    double pr= Double.parseDouble(preis.getText().toString());
    String kom=kommentar.getText().toString();

    selected.setPreis(pr);
    selected.setBeschreibung(kom);

    pd.update(selected);
}
```

}

MyProduct class

```
public class MyProduct {

private long id;
private String lebensmittel;
private double preis;
private String beschreibung;
private int image;


public MyProduct()
{
    this.id=0;
    this.lebensmittel = "Birne";
    this.preis=0;
    this.beschreibung= "teuer";
    this.image = 1;
}

public MyProduct(long id, String lebensmittel, double preis, String beschreibung, int image)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.lebensmittel = lebensmittel;
    this.preis=preis;
    this.beschreibung= beschreibung;
    this.image = image;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getLebensmittel() {
    return lebensmittel;
}


public void setLebensmittel(String lebensmittel) {
    this.lebensmittel = lebensmittel;
}


public double getPreis() {
    return preis;
}


public void setPreis(double preis) {
    this.preis = preis;
}


public String getBeschreibung() {
    return beschreibung;
}


public void setBeschreibung(String beschreibung) {
    this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
}


public int getImage() {
    return image;
}


public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

```
public class ProductDao implements Dao<MyProduct>{


private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteStatement insertStatement;
private String DB_Table = "products";
private String INSERT = "insert into " + DB_Table
        + "(idi,product,price,comment,imgid)" + "values (?,?,?,?,?)";
private String SEL_ROW = "select idi,product,price,comment from "
        + DB_Table;
private String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + DB_Table
        + "( idi long NOT NULL, " + " product String NOT NULL, "
        + " price double, " + " comment String, " + " imgid int)";
private String CREATE_INDEX = "create index if not exists " + DB_Table
        + "_ind " + "ON " + DB_Table + " (idi)";

public ProductDao(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;
    try {
        insertStatement = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "Create INSERT product");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "NO Database, NO INSERT product");
    }
}

@Override
public long save(MyProduct product) {
    insertStatement.clearBindings();
    insertStatement.bindLong(1, product.getId());
    // TODO !!!!
    return insertStatement.executeInsert();
}

@Override
public void update(MyProduct type) {
}

@Override
public void delete(MyProduct type) {
}

@Override
public MyProduct get(long id) {
    Cursor cs = db.rawQuery(SEL_ROW + " where idi=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    if (cs.moveToFirst())
        return buildProductFromCursor(cs);
    else
        return null;
}

@Override
public List<MyProduct> getAll() {
    List <MyProduct>list= new ArrayList<MyProduct>();
    // Select All Query
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select idi,product,price,comment,imgid from products", null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            MyProduct product = new MyProduct();
            product.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            product.setLebensmittel(cursor.getString(1));
            product.setPreis(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
            product.setBeschreibung(cursor.getString(3));
            product.setImage(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));

            // Adding contact to list
            list.add(product);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    return list;
}

private MyProduct buildProductFromCursor(Cursor cs) {
    MyProduct product = null;
    if (cs == null)
        Log.e("Internal Error", "no cursor");
    else {
        Log.v("ANDRO VEGI", toString(cs));
        product = new MyProduct(cs.getLong(0), cs.getString(1),
                cs.getDouble(2), cs.getString(3), cs.getInt(4));
    }
    return product;
}

public void createTable() {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_INDEX);
    try {
        insertStatement = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "Create INSERT product");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "NO Database, NO INSERT product");
    }
}

public void fillTable() {
    long ok = 0;
    if (ok > -1)
        ok = save(new MyProduct(1, "Äpfel", 0,
                "neue Lieferung vom Huberbauer", R.drawable.apfel_70x70));
    if (ok > -1)
        ok = save(new MyProduct(2, "Birnen", 0,
                "Achtung sehr süss aber überreif", R.drawable.birne_70x70));
    if (ok > -1)
        ok = save(new MyProduct(3, "Karotten", 0, "wie immer",
                R.drawable.karotte_70x70));
    if (ok > -1)
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "OK INSERT products ");
    else
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "INSERT products failed");
}

String toString(Cursor cs) {
    String sh = "";
    try {
        sh += cs.getLong(0) + "," + cs.getLong(0) + "," + cs.getString(1)
                + "," + cs.getDouble(2) + "," + cs.getString(3) + ","
                + cs.getInt(4);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sh += "***,";
    }
    return sh;
}
```

}

Comment: What does your adapter's getCount method return?

Comment: I have no getCount method in my adapter class. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Right, sorry about that. What's the size of your ArrayList<MyProduct> then? You have to check if the problem is with your Adapter or somewhere else.

Comment: Do i have to define the size of it? I thought only with normal Arrays.

Comment: No, you don't. But if it's size happens to be 0 then the Spinner's adapter has nothing to show when you click it.

Comment: Right but when i do this:

 try{
        products=(ArrayList<MyProduct>)pd.getAll();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
the size should be 3 then because i only have 3 products

Comment: Well, is its size 3?

Comment: i tried to put the size into the preis edittext but it doesnt work it seems that the ArrayList does not get any data in it. I dont know why.